# jsfiddle for ajax POST JSON echo

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to do jquery ajax POST of an object as JSON and get it echoed back

```
var dict = { key1: 'val1', key2: 10 };

$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dict),
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert('data='+JSON.stringify(data));

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('error');
});
```

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d688qah/1/)

But no luck - I'm getting an empty {}

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: have a php code which will return you the json you pass, currently the url exists but has nothing to give in return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok figured it out from http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

"
Data has to be provided via POST
json
  is a JSON string representing the object jsFiddle should return. It has to be         valid JSON or error will be returned
delay
  optional, it’s a time in seconds after which data should be returned
"

So it should be:

```
var dict = { key1: 'val1', key2: 10 };

$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {json: JSON.stringify(dict) },
    success:function(data){
    alert('data='+JSON.stringify(data));}
});
```

Comment: please mark @madalin ivascu answer as answer .. he/she already told this